# Good Windows 7 themes that don't modify critical system components

Tags: windows-7, themes

Are there any attractive themes for Windows 7 that do not modify critical system files, such as `explorer.exe` or `shell.dll`?

I found some nice themes on [DeviantArt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeviantArt), but they all make these extreme changes - I really don't want to mess around with Windows' stability.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a number of themes posted at http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/personalize .

Comment: I would recommend just looking at Windows 7 themes from this site, as they just modify your wallpaper and your window/taskbar colors...and they can be undone and modified at *any* time, easily. +1 @sound2man

Comment: the microsoft themes are ugly like hell